# Update multiple javascript object properties at once

Tags: javascript

Is there a short-hand to do the following:

```
let o = {}
o['a'] = 1;
o['b'] = 2;
```

For example, either:

```
let o = {}
o.update({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

Or:

```
let o = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object.assign` can achieve it.

```js
const o = { original: 'orig' };
Object.assign(o, {'a': 1, 'b': 2});

console.log(o);
```

Comment: thanks, why do you declare it as `const` in the above case? Wouldn't the updating of the object make it 'un-const' ?

Comment: `const` indicates that the variable won't be *reassigned* - that `o = somethingElse` won't happen later. It's good practice to use `const` to declare variables when possible (which it is, 95% of the time) to make code more readable. Reassignment is not the same thing as mutation. Mutation assigns to a *property* of the object, reassignment changes what the whole variable name points to. `const` only prohibits reassignment.

Comment: thanks, that's a really helpful explanation. By the way, to look up all the properties/methods of an object, how do you normally do that? For example in python I'll do something like: `dir(set())` and get `['pop', 'remove', ...]`.

Comment: `Object.keys` usually. If you want the values too, `Object.entries`. Only values: `Object.values`. Non-enumerable properties too (rare): `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`. Properties that are non-enumerable *and* prototypal: recursive `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`

Comment: Do you have to enumerate them in a `for` loop in order to read them? For example, if I just do: `console.log(Object.keys, Object.values, Object.values);` it prints `[Function: keys] [Function: values] [Function: values]`.

Comment: They're functions you have to invoke. See [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/) for details on all.